# Linq - Grouping by date and selecting count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am currently working through a problem where I would like to run a query which groups the results by the date selected.

For this example, imagine a simple model like so:

```
public class User
{
      public DateTime LastLogIn {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The solution I am looking for is to get a count of Users logged in by Date.
In the database the DateTime are stored with both date and time components, but for this query I really only care about the date.

What I currently have is this:

```
    context.Users
            .Where((x.LastLogIn  >= lastWeek)    
                && (x.LastLogIn <= DateTime.Now))
            .GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LastLogIn))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Value = x.Count(),
                Day = (DateTime)EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Key)
            }).ToList();
```

The above however returns an empty list.

End goal is to have a List of objects, which contain a Value (the count of users logged in on a day) and a Day (the day in question)

Any thoughts?

Upon changing the query to:

```
    context.Users
            .Where((x.LastLogIn  >= lastWeek)    
                && (x.LastLogIn <= DateTime.Now))
            .GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LastLogIn))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Value = x.Count(),
                Day = (DateTime)x.Key
            }).ToList();
```

it now returns a list with a single item, with the Value being the total count of Users that match the where clause, and the Day being the very first day.  It still hasn't seemed to be able to group by the days

**NOTE:** turns out the above code is right, I was just doing something else wrong.

Sql that it is generating is (note might be very slight syntactical errors here with me adjusting it for the example):

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
 CAST( [GroupBy1].[K1] AS datetime2) AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
        [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
        COUNT([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
                 convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[LastLogIn], 102) ,  102) AS [K1], 
                1 AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE (([Extent1].[LastLogIn] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[LastLogIn] <= @p__linq__2)
        )  AS [Filter1]
       GROUP BY [K1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: The query looks OK. Do you get a non-zero value back when you replace `GroupBy` with a straight `Count()`?

Comment: Running with a straight count returns the count expected that matches the where clause, it seems to be the grouping that is killing it

Comment: Did you try replacing `Day = (DateTime)EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Key)` with `Day = x.Key`? It should be the same, because the date is already truncated for grouping.

Comment: Ok, removing that has changed some things, it now returns a list with a single item.  Will update question with detail

Comment: On the outside, this looks like a bug in the EF. Did you try capturing SQL and running it in your DB directly to see what's happening?

Comment: Yea, it appears to be doing a lot of casting of dates and weirdness.  Wonder if there is a workaround...

Comment: I would try something like this: `GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LastLogIn), x => 1)` to see if grouping `User`s has anything to do with the bug.

Comment: @Thewads I tested this locally, and it works fine for me.  I had to adjust your query a bit because the sytnax was a bit off.  But this is what I used: `var results = context.Users.Where(x => x.LastLogIn >= lastWeek && x.LastLogIn <= DateTime.Now).GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LastLogIn)).Select(x => new { Value = x.Count(), Day = (DateTime)x.Key }).ToList();`

Comment: @Khan that is odd, the exact same style of syntax for me is returning a total count in a single list item as described above

Comment: It will be useful to look at the generated SQL by SQL Profiler for example

Comment: Have put the generated SQL into question

Comment: Is it possible that a culture setting somewhere could be making all of your dates seem to be on the same day?

Comment: @khan unlikely, any other date queries are working fine

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I must have had something done wrong in my local code as your edit earlier does seemed to have fixed it.  If you want to note it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: does this work on .net core?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You do not need the second `TruncateTime` in there:

```
context.Users
    .Where((x.LastLogIn  >= lastWeek) && (x.LastLogIn <= DateTime.Now))
    .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LastLogIn))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Value = x.Count(),
        // Replace the commented line
        //Day = (DateTime)DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Key)
        // ...with this line
        Day = (DateTime)x.Key
    }).ToList();
```

The `GroupBy` has truncated the time from the `DateTime` already, so you do not need to call it again.

To use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` you'll need to reference the assembly `System.Data.Entity` and include `using System.Data.Entity;`

**Note:** Edited to address deprecation of `EntityFunctions`.

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LastLogIn))` is important factor here for considering datewise grouping.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hi, what change do I have to make in your solution to include the days that have count = 0? I need to return all the days in the timeframe even if there are no logins. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick I don't think you can do it: LINQ will not return a result unless it in the database. You can convert the results to a dictionary, and then go through the range of dates, one day at a time, and grab the data from the dictionary if it is available.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 .GroupBy(x => new {Year = x.LastLogIn.Year, Month = x.LastLogIn.Month, Day = x.LastLogIn.Day)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Value = x.Count(),
                    Year = x.Key.Year,
                    Month = x.Key.Month,
                    Day = x.Key.Day
                })
```

Comment: hey, this is in the same situation as described above, with it returning a list with a single item which has a count of all the items

Comment: May be working (although somehow nasty), but why the original query doesn't work?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it easily:

```
yourDateList.GroupBy(i => i.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
             .Select(i => new
             {
                 Date = DateTime.ParseExact(i.Key, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None),
                 Count = i.Count()
             });
```

Comment: It "seems" less valid. But I've used this approach many many many times with fantastic success. Especially coming from the standpoint that "yyyyMMdd" is the universally accepted date format for SQL Server when passing data through.

Comment: I wonder if this works and all the solutions suggesting a `new` SomethingOrOther don't because the string is grouped by value and the others are grouped by reference.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this same problem to get a count based on group by a datetime column. This is what i did. Thanks for some of the answers here. I tried the minimal version and I used this code in .netcore solution.

```
var result = _context.yourdbmodel
              .GroupBy(x=>x.yourdatetimecolumn.Value.Date)
              .select(x=> new 
              {
                Count = x.Count(),
                Date = (DateTime)x.Key // or x.Key.Date (excluding time info) or x.Key.Date.ToString() (give only Date in string format) 
              })
              .ToList();
```

Sample output:

> [   {
>       "requestDate": "2020-04-01",
>       "requestCount": 3   },   {
>       "requestDate": "2020-04-07",
>       "requestCount": 14   } ]

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: You did well, this helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in one line.

```
var b = (from a in ctx.Candidates select a)
            .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedTimestamp.Date).Select(g => new { Date=(g.Key).ToShortDateString(), Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just convert first IQueryable to IEnumerable(List) with the help of ToList() then use groupby

```
context.Users
            .Where((x.LastLogIn  >= lastWeek) && (x.LastLogIn <= DateTime.Now))
            .ToList()
            .GroupBy(x => x.LastLogIn.Date))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Value = x.Count(),
                Day = (DateTime)x.Key
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Bad advice. This pulls more data into memory than necessary, possibly *a lot* more.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for your comment Actually there is no filter or where condition so if we use  ToList before or After groupby will give same output and I have also test in my machine so can you please explain how it pulls more data into memory.

Comment: The grouping + count is an aggregate. A possibly large amount of records in the database results in only a couple of small items (Key + count). The `ToList` pulls up all filtered data (having all columns) after which the aggregation in memory discards most of it. Also, there are plenty of answers. No need to add anything to them.

Comment: Thank you @GertArnold for the explanation, I will improve my answer

Comment: I don't think a new answer is necessary.

Comment: TruncateTime is not working in my case and I have used both DBfuction and EntityFuction

Comment: That's not the point. It's all about getting way too much data.