# How to group by Date.Date c# and return object?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Say i have a database table called `Registration` with these properties:

- `public DateTime DateReference { get; set; }`
- `public int MinuteWorked { get; set; }`
- `public int Status { get; set; }`

The table has over 200K+ records...

How can i group all the records based on the DateReference for instance:

- group all the records where the date day is equal

**SO:**

- it would be check all the records DateReference and then group the ones that are equal into lists?

So far i've been trying to do everything with `GroupBy` but still no clue on how to make this query simple and as efficent as possible? Please help me, i've been all day here at my desk trying to solve this...

Comment: i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225895/linq-grouping-by-date-and-selecting-count has the awnser you are looking for

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work because i don't have a select date but rather sql has to find the dates that matches

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the query or queries you've tried with GroupBy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by records from database based on date (day) c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825373/how-to-group-by-records-from-database-based-on-date-day-c)

Comment: I was able to find a solution, but since i have 200k+ records in the database the query takes sooooo long. So i am currently trying to find out if i can take small portion of the database to do the GroupBy...

Comment: I don't think is possibile to tell c# to GroupBy specific `keys` (say like 20 days). To implement a pagination of some sort. The number of the page and the size will be provided by front end....